# Home Ownership Entitlement

Tags: home-ownership, home

I need some advise please. Me and my girlfriend bought a house together. The cost of the property was R720 000.00. I gave R500 000 cash and she got a bond registred in her name for the remaining R220 000. So the house is registered in her name now. 
Our relationship has gone bad now, and she claims it is her house now and i need to move out. She still owes R223 500 on the bond loan, in 3 years time she has only paid back the interest. I drew up a lawyers letter to say how we devided the money of the house but she made sure the document got lost. What am I to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is now a legal matter, not one of personal finance. Get a lawyer immediately.

Answer (score 2):

This story painfully illustrates why is is *extremely important* that anyone buying a house, or other significant asset, jointly draws up a legal agreement stipulating how much of the asset is owned by who and how it should be divided if the relationship breaks down. Such agreements are extremely cheap to draw up compared with the cost of not having one.

As ChrisInEdmonton says, the only person who can help you now is a lawyer. Get one immediately. The battle to get anything will be uphill now because the house is registered in your girlfriend's name.

For the record, here are some mistakes that led to this. I'm not listing them to make you feel bad, but in the hope that someone reading this who is about to buy a house jointly will read it and not have the same problems.

1. **You didn't get a legal agreement drawn up and signed**. You should always do this.
2. **You allowed the house to be registered in your girlfriend's name.** This means that in the eyes of the law the house appears to be hers, and it's going to be up to you to show anything different.
3. **Not keeping a copy of the 'lawyers letter'.**

As a final thought, in some countries if you have been living with your girlfriend for three years, you are considered to be married to her, and any property should be divided as if you were getting divorced. I have no idea if this applies in your country.